# Automatically center a UIImageView after rotation

Tags: iphone

I have an UIImage inside an UIImageView in my application.

In portrait mode, the image is centered but when I switch to the landscape mode it stills on the left.

So I added the following method in my .m file but the problem is that I have a TabBar application, so when I rotate the device on another tab and I go back to the tab containing the image, it doesn't rotate automatically.

There is a way to rotate automatically all the elements of the application when rotating the device on any tab ?

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
        background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back2-landscape.png"];
    } else  if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){
        background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back2-portrait.png"];
    }
}
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two options:

*1. Do in in IB - Turn *off* all those little spaces and arrows in the "Autosizing" area under the "Size Inspector". You should be able to then "Simulate Interface", and rotate the [simulated] device, with the object staying centered.

[image]

*2. Do it programmatically, in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation by doing something like:

```
[theObject setCenter:self.center];
```

Comment: I did it using the first method and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much :-)